# Winform Login Form with userlevel

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have a table of user_data and has a column for userlevel i want access to different form for different user level access here is my source code

for example

Select username,password from user_data where username = username and password = password and userlevel = 1 - for form1

Select username,password from user_data where username = username and password = password and userlevel = 2 - for form2

```
        if ((txtusername.Text.Trim() != "") && (txtpassword.Text.Trim() != "")) // to validate if user and pass have data

                {
                    String passwords = encryption(txtpassword.Text.Trim()); 
                    string q = "SELECT username, password FROM user_data WHERE (UserName = '" + txtusername.Text.ToString() + "') AND (Password = '" + passwords + "');";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", this.txtusername.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", this.txtpassword.Text.Trim());
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        if (dr.HasRows == true)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Login", "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                            this.Hide();
                            Form1 shForm1 = new Form1();
                            shForm1.FormClosed += (_, args) => this.Close();
                            shForm1.ShowDialog();

                        }
                    }
                    if (dr.HasRows == false)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username and Password", "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Enter username and password", "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
```

Any idea will do I'm a beginner here at winform development
Thank you ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you include "username, password" into select?

If you need just 'user level access', you can use this(or something like this):

```
string q = "SELECT **userlevel** FROM user_data WHERE (UserName = '" + txtusername.Text.ToString() + "') AND (Password = '" + passwords + "');";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", this.txtusername.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", this.txtpassword.Text.Trim());
object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(obj != null)
{
     if((int)obj == 1)
     {
        Window1 wnd = new Window1();
        wnd.Open();
     }
     else
     {
        Window2 wnd = new Window2();
        wnd.Open();
     }
}
else
{
   // kick
}
```

Comment: This is unsecure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection, its like you've half thought of parameterizing the query but you've put the textboxes in the sql.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a factory to generate different forms for different user.
Input user level as well as other params to the factory and get an abstract Form.
Something like this:

```
AbstractForm form = FormFactory.GetForm(userLevel,otherParams...);
```

And you need to read user information from database before.

By the way, FormFactory is something like this:

```
class FormFacotry
{
//Key is user level and value is Form.
Dictionary<int,Form> formTable=new Dictionary<string,Form>();

static FormFacotry()
{
//Prepare relation between user level and Form.
formTable.Add(1,new Form1());
formTable.Add(2,new Form2());
}

public Form GetForm(int userlevel,...)
{
return formTable[userleval];
}
}
```